# How do I calculate the difference between and percentile of properties?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a neo4j graph that I have modeled as:

```
MERGE (c1:ChangeTime {at:1800})
MERGE (c2:ChangeTime {at:1900})
MERGE (c3:ChangeTime {at:2200})
MERGE (p:Profile {name:"ME"})
MERGE (p)-[:UPDATED_ON]->(c1)
MERGE (p)-[:UPDATED_ON]->(c2)
MERGE (p)-[:UPDATED_ON]->(c3)
```

This is basically a simplified view of an individual's profile that is updated at different change times.

what is the cypher query to get the difference between each ChangeTime's 'at' property so I know how frequency of the change?

And also how do I calculate the percentile for a specific 'difference' value?

Trying to find the fastest way to apply this in a large graph.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "how frequency of the change", do you actually mean "the rate of change"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the Cypher query to get the difference between each ChangeTime's 'at' property so I know how frequency of the change?

If you have to stick to plain Cypher, you can use a [list comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#_list_comprehension):

```
MATCH (p:Profile)-[:UPDATED_ON]->(ct:ChangeTime)
WITH p, ct
ORDER BY ct.at
WITH p, collect(ct.at) AS ct_ats
RETURN p, [i IN range(0, length(ct_ats)-2) | ct_ats[i+1] - ct_ats[i]] AS diffs
```

This returns:

```
╒══════════╤══════════╕
│p         │diffs     │
╞══════════╪══════════╡
│{name: ME}│[100, 300]│
└──────────┴──────────┘
```

To determine the minimum and the maximum of the diff values, you have to `UNWIND` the collection and use the `min` and `max` aggregation functions:

```
MATCH (p:Profile)-[:UPDATED_ON]->(ct:ChangeTime)
WITH p, ct
ORDER BY ct.at
WITH p, collect(ct.at) AS ct_ats
WITH p, [i IN range(0, length(ct_ats)-2) | ct_ats[i+1] - ct_ats[i]] AS diffs
UNWIND diffs AS diff
RETURN p, min(diff) AS minDiff, max(diff) AS maxDiff
```

This gives:

```
╒══════════╤═══════╤═══════╕
│p         │minDiff│maxDiff│
╞══════════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│{name: ME}│100    │300    │
└──────────┴───────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I copied and pasted the query as it is but it only returns/visually shows a node for p but not the table comprising of p and diffs column. What if I only want the smallest and largest difference in diffs for all th profiles/p's?

Comment: @user716222 to get the table, simply choose "Text" output (from the Graph, Rows, Text and Code options, left to the results).

Comment: @user716222 I updated the answer with a query to give the smallest and largest differences.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find APOC Procedures helpful, especially the [collection functions](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_collection_functions). Especially apoc.coll.pairsMin(), which takes a collection parameter and returns a collection of pairs (so an input of [1,2,3,4,5] would return [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]]).

So one approach using this, to get the intervals between changes for a particular user, is something like this:

```
MATCH (:Profile {name:"ME"})-[:UPDATED_ON]->(c:ChangeTime)
WITH c
ORDER BY c.at DESC
WITH COLLECT(c) as updates
CALL apoc.coll.pairsMin(updates) YIELD value
UNWIND value as updatePairs
WITH updatePairs[0] as update1, updatePairs[1] as update2
SET update1.interval = update1.at - update2.at
```

And now that you have the interval, you can match on a user's :ChangeTime nodes and get the average interval with avg() when needed.

As for percentile, there are aggregation functions for discrete and continuous percentile, please see the aggregations section of the [Cypher ref card](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/).

Comment: The query returns an error:

Invalid input '[': expected an identifier character, node labels, a property map, whitespace, a relationship pattern, '(', '.', '=' or "+=" (line 7, column 16 (offset: 200))
"SET updatePairs[0].interval = updatePairs[0].at - updatePairs[1].at"
                ^

Comment: Cypher can get finicky about setting values on elements of a collection. I updated the query to alias each part of the pair, see if that fixes it.